# A better way of writing a scope with lambda to pull records then .count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I currently have these scopes to pull records of Tasks in specific date ranges on a Customer record.

```
scope :by_current_month, lambda { where("created_at >= '{date.beginning_of_month.to_s(:db)}' AND created_at <= '#{date.end_of_month.to_s(:db)}'") }
scope :by_months_ago, lambda { |month| where("created_at >= '#{date.months_ago(month).beginning_of_month.to_s(:db)}' AND created_at <= '#{date.months_ago(month).end_of_month.to_s(:db)}'") }
scope :in_last_year, lambda { where("start_date >= '#{date.months_ago(12).beginning_of_month.to_s(:db)}' AND start_date <= '#{date.months_ago(0).end_of_month.to_s(:db)}'") }
```

These are all pulled on the Customers index page in a table. There's a load of queries which slows the page load significantly. I can't quite figure out the best method of either caching or doing something to help the speed.

```
<%= customer.tasks.find_by_status(1).count %>
<%= customer.tasks.by_current_month.count %>
<%= customer.tasks.in_last_year.count %>
```

This generates plenty of these queries:

```
Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."customer_id" = 1 AND (STATUS NOT IN (4,5))
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."customer_id" = 1 AND (created_at >= '2013-06-01' AND created_at <= '2013-06-30')
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."customer_id" = 1 AND (start_date >= '2012-06-01' AND start_date <= '2013-06-30')
```

Comment: Are you indexing all the fields you're searching on?

Comment: 0.1ms doesn't seem long. However, you could cache these values in a separate table and re-calculate them if a task is added or removed.

Comment: I'm not indexing anything :( Yeah, it isn't long but there's like a good 100+ queries in total.